# Why is the template re-rendered even though the input doesn't change when using OnPush strategy?

Tags: angular

Currently trying to get my head around this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `value: {{value|json}} <button (click)="setValue()">set</button>`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class TestComponent {
  @Input() name!: string;
  value = false;

  setValue() {
    timer(100)
      .subscribe(() => this.value = true);
  }
}
```

Clicking on the button does **not** trigger a re-render immediately, **but** clicking it a second time causes the view to get updated.

Removing the `changeDetection` from the component (or setting it to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default`) also causes the view to immediately being re-rendered after clicking the button.

What's really confuses me at this point is:

- why is the view even re-rendered at all when using the `OnPush` strategy? As far as I've understood this strategy shouldn't it only be re-rendered on `@Input` changes?
- why is it re-rendered after clicking the button *twice*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button click triggers a refresh because you are subscribing to the click event. Event handlers inside a component also trigger a change detection to run.

The first time it does not look like it refreshes because you add a delay and the component refresh happens before the value changes.

Comment: Makes sense. Tried to change the observable to `of(true)` which causes an instant re-render. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, on DOM events angular runs a change detection cycle even with OnPush strategy. In fact this is the only asynchronous API (DOM) that triggers a change detection cycle when using OnPush strategy.

My guess is that is changing the value on the second click because of the timer.

This is great post on the subject [A Comprehensive Guide to Angular onPush Change Detection Strategy](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4)